# WPF GridSplitter not being hit-tested?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, gridsplitter

I seem to run into a strange problem with WPF GridSplitter.

If I do this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="102" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="192" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Black"></GridSplitter>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue"></Canvas>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow"></Canvas>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can see the GridSplitter, but I cannot interact with it - mouse over it and cursor does not change and cannot resize rows with it.

Now if I change the order of the elements added to the grid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="102" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="192" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue"></Canvas>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow"></Canvas>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Black"></GridSplitter>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Then the GridSplitter is working fine. 
Note that I put `Panel.ZIndex="1"` in the first case for the GridSplitter, it will also work.

Then I tried this (added `UseLayoutRounding="True"` to `Window`):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="102" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="192" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" Background="Black"></GridSplitter>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue"></Canvas>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow"></Canvas>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This gives me a strange behaviour: Initially the Gridsplitter is being drawn with a height of 2px (sub-pixel positioning? but all the grid rows are integer height). If I resize the rows upwards, GridSplitter continues to work. If I resize the rows downwards I will get to a point where GridSplitter is being drawn with a height of 1px and once I release the mouse I can no longer interact with the GridSplitter.

**Questions:**

1. **Why does GridSplitter depend on Z-order to work in the first two cases?**
2. **Why does GridSplitter work "intermittently" in the third case?**

Comment: I think that it works in both of the first two cases independent of z-order. When I try it works with both, but just being one pixel high makes it hard to "hit". Try making it 4 pixels and try again.

Comment: Actually if I change the first case to 2 px it works. But with 1px GridSplitter, I've tried on two different computers and both not work.

Comment: It works for me using Windows 8 on a Retina MBP (2880*1800px) but it's quite hard to "hit it". Your hunch about subpixels ands stuff is probably correct and I suggest you stick to a height of >1 pixel :)

Comment: Also, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742210(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link but the link only describes how to ensure the gridsplitter is visible for putting a gridsplitter in the same grid cell as some other elements. In the question I am clearing putting the gridsplitter in its own grid cell, which is a different problem.